# Rewrite to file is not working when directory for given request uri exists in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have these folders:

```
projects/
├─ foobar.html
projects.html
projects_page=1.html
projects_page=2.html
```

and this requested uri: `http://localhost:8888/subdir/en/projects?page=2`

and this htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes 
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/ %1_page=%2.html [L,R=307,QSD]
```

I expect that `projects_page=2.html` is being output, instead I get a 403 forbidden. If I enable directory listings (`+Indexes`) I get the directory listing instead.

How can I define in htaccess to prioritize my rewrite to a file when a uri is requested for that a folder exists?

Running on MAMP 6.

Comment: I don't see `subdir` ib the list of folders. Is `subdir` parent directory of `projects`?

Comment: @anubhava Its just an example. Why is that important? Its a deep folder structure of html files, there is only this htaccess file.

Comment: Can you request `projects_page=2.html` _directly_, or is that also giving you a 403 response? `=` in folder names feels very ... "icky" to begin with. You might be dealing with URL encoding issues here, I suppose. Maybe the `NE` no escape flag can help? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Comment: 1. Important is to understand your directory structure corresponding to your URL and 2. If this is in .htaccess then `RewriteRule ^/` will always fail

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I can access the file directly. `=` is only in the html filename, but encoding isnt an issue on my local machine. `_` is actually another character that works fine

Comment: @anubhava Why would `^/` fail? It works for my other tests

Comment: Trust it is Apace only, a leading `/` in `RewriteRule` doesn't match because URI path a .htaccess matches is relative to the directory it is placed in.

Comment: @anubhava No, the documentation says the Pattern (first argument when using RewriteRule) is relative to the host, so the part after `http://localhost:8888`

Comment: @anubhava I mean Im happy to change it, what is your idea?

Comment: @anubhava Thats what I meant: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/intro.html#rewriterule its possible I misunderstand it, tho

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule: _"In per-directory context (Directory and .htaccess) [...] The directory path where the rule is defined is stripped from the currently mapped filesystem path before comparison (**up to and including a trailing slash**). The net result of this per-directory prefix stripping is that rules in this context only match against the portion of the currently mapped filesystem path "below" where the rule is defined."_

Comment: @CBroe Ah, so my Pattern is wrong

Comment: My problem is that locally the directory path is long and deep while on live it will be just a domain without any sub directories. I cannot use a VHost config locally

Comment: You want to match all possible paths there, and don't need to capture anything - so just a single `.` as pattern should suffice.

Comment: @CBroe It adds my file system path at the beginning now: `http://localhost:8888/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/subdir/more-subdirs/2%ef%b9%96page=.html` I will try to figure out the right hand side later (there does seem to be some encoding issues) but `RewriteRule . ...` doesnt seem to work

Comment: No, _that_ part appears to have worked - otherwise, you would not get redirected _anywhere_, but since you are landing on that wrong URL that includes your file system path, you must have gotten _redirected_ there? You might perhaps need to specify a RewriteBase, or indeed deal with URL encoding issues.

Comment: `RewriteRule . /%1_page=%2.html [L,R=307,QSD]` will not add filesystem path

Comment: @anubhava That gives me `http://localhost:8888/2%ef%b9%96page=.html` :D God I hate htaccess

Comment: @CBroe currently no redirects active

Answer (score 0):

What turned out to be working for me locally is this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1﹖page=%1.html [L]
```

The important changes being that when you dont want a redirect (which sometimes happened) dont use `[R]` and either use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]` in combination with `[L]` or use `[END]` instead of `[L]`.